# Sending a URL with multiple variables as a parameter to another page

Tags: php, jquery, url, query-string

I have a Javascript page, that sends data to a PHP page. That data is a URL with different querystrings, for example:

```
    var localURL = "http://localhost/app/proxy.php?data=http://myserver.com/game.php?type=loadgame&userInfoName=AA&userPwd=AA&nocache=0.8046834595784704"

    $.ajax({
        url: localURL,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            alert('beforesend');
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success: ' + data);
        }
    });
```

The number of querystring variables can vary, so I can't send it with the data parameter of the ajax function. If I do a GET of the data variable ($_GET['data'];) I get this result:

http://myserver.com//game.php?type=loadgame

and what I'd like to get is:

http://myserver.com/game.php?type=loadgame&userInfoName=AA&userPwd=AA&nocache=0.8046834595784704

Any idea? :-S

Comment: Well you're sending it to `proxy.php` and the URL is using `game.php`; are you sure `proxy.php` is correctly forwarding the query string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You gotta escape to get a valid url:

```
var data = escape('http://myserver.com/game.php?type=loadgame&userInfoName=AA&userPwd=AA&nocache=0.8046834595784704');
var localURL = "http://localhost/app/proxy.php?data=" . data;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing, is URL escaping in `localUrl` varaible.

It should be like this:

```
var localURL = "http://localhost/app/proxy.php?data=http%3A%2F%2Fmyserver.com%2Fgame.php%3Ftype%3Dloadgame%26userInfoName%3DAA%26userPwd%3DAA%26nocache%3D0.8046834595784704"
```

if you construct the localURL in javascript, use `escape()` function

Answer (score 0):

```
var localURL = "http://localhost/app/proxy.php?data=" + encodeURIComponent("http://myserver.com/game.php?type=loadgame&userInfoName=AA&userPwd=AA&nocache=0.8046834595784704");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what the browser sees:

```
http://localhost/app/proxy.php?

data=http://myserver.com/game.php?type=loadgame => param 1

&userInfoName=AA => param 2

&userPwd=AA => param 3

&nocache=0.8046834595784704 => param 4
```

so you should escape the string "http://myserver.com/game.php?type=loadgame&userInfoName=AA&userPwd=AA&nocache=0.8046834595784704" like this

```
var data=$.URLEncode('http://myserver.com/game.php?type=loadgame&userInfoName=AA&userPwd=AA&nocache=0.8046834595784704')
```

Comment: It's worth updating your answer to say a plugin is required for `$.URLEncode` to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the reserved characters. jQuery can do this for your automatically if you restructure like so:

```
var localURL = "http://localhost/app/proxy.php";
var getString = "http://myserver.com/game.php?type=loadgame&userInfoName=AA&userPwd=AA&nocache=0.8046834595784704";

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    data: { data: getString },
    url: localURL,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        alert('beforesend');
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert('success: ' + data);
    }
});
```

Will request for:

> http://localhost/app/proxy.php?data=http%3A%2F%2Fmyserver.com%2Fgame.php%3Ftype%3Dloadgame%26userInfoName%3DAA%26userPwd%3DAA%26nocache%3D0.8046834595784704